# R webscraping "SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired" but works in browser. Need to parse HTML to JSON

Tags: r, json, ssl, web-scraping

I've come up with a partial solution to my question, but still need help getting to the end.

My issue is that I can no longer get JSON from a website using R, but I can still access it via my browser:

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

website <- 'http://api.draftkings.com/sites/US-DK/sports/v1/sports?format=json'
fromJSON(website)
```

Now gives me:
`Error in open.connection(con, "rb") :  SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired` but I'm still able to visit the site on Chrome.

**Ideally I'd like to find a way to get this working using `fromJSON()`**

I don't entirely understand what's causing this error, so I tried a bunch of different solutions. I found that I could at least read the html using this:

```
website <- 'http://api.draftkings.com/sites/US-DK/sports/v1/sports?format=json'
doc <- webpage %>% 
  httr::GET(config = httr::config(ssl_verifypeer = FALSE)) %>% 
  read_html()
```

However, from here I'm stuck. I'm struggling trying to parse the doc to the JSON I require. I've tried things like `doc %>% xmlParse() %>% xmlToList() %>% toJSON() %>% fromJSON()` but it comes out as gibberish.

So my question comes down to: 1) is there a way to get around the SSL certificate problem so that I can use `fromJSON()` directly again. And 2) if not, how can I sanitize the html document to get it in a usable JSON format?

Comment: This has to do with the Let's Encrypt root certificate that expired on Sept 30. The trusted certificates that shipped with your operating system need to be updated. The underlying system libraries are what R uses to do these requests.

Comment: Thanks @Brian so sounds like first step is updating my OS? I have a 2019 MacBook running Catalina v10.15.4. Thank you for your help

Comment: You can update your OS, or you can manually add the new root certificate (and critically, delete the old one) on your keychain. However, the way you're using `httr` in your second code snippet, you should be able to replace `read_html` with `...%>% content(as = "text") %>% fromJSON()`, since the SSL config you passed in is bypassing the certificates.

Comment: Interesting so my certificate com.apple.systemdefault says it doesn't expire until 2037, which makes me think that's not the issue. Any thoughts? But the second part of your solution works for me, so no worries if I can't get the first part. Thank you!

Comment: The problem is also affecting Curl, Read_html and many other tools.  Overriding using set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L)) has failed.  An example that causes the error follows.    
 library(httr)
Targetpage = "http://erddap.gcoos.org/erddap/tabledap/wmo_42932.htmlTable?time%2Clatitude%2Clongitude%2Cdepth%2Csea_water_speed_0%2Csea_water_direction_0&time%3E=2021-10-02T00%3A00%3A00UTC&time%3C=2021-10-04T13%3A24%3A00UTC"

 read_html(Targetpage)